# RunOnce not running on startup

Tags: powershell

I've got an issue with my startup scripts not running on restart.

I'm trying to have my system do a bunch of scripts, but restart after each one runs, etc. This script will set the registry key, but after it auto-logons, powershell doesn't run at all.

```
#Sets Autologin for scripts
$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion \Winlogon"
$DefaultUsername = Read-Host -Prompt "User's O365 Cred"
$DefaultPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "User's O365 Pass"
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "1" -type String
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultUsername" -Value "$DefaultUsername" -type String
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultPassword" -Value "$DefaultPassword" -type String


#Reboots and starts next script
$RunOnceKey = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
set-itemproperty $RunOnceKey "NextRun" ('C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe  -File ' + "~\Downloads\systemrename.ps1")
Start-Sleep 10
Restart-Computer
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I haven't tried what you are doing but you can use a scheduled task to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Solution via Scheduled Task:

```
## Create the action
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument '-Command "c:\temp\systemrename.ps1"'

## Set to run as local system, No need to store Credentials!!!
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

## set to run at startup could also do -AtLogOn for the trigger
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup

## register it (save it) and it will show up in default folder of task scheduler.
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -TaskName 'mytask' -TaskPath '\' -Principal $principal -Trigger $trigger
```

Note all of these commands support remoting via a cimsession, like so:

```
## Create remote cimsession
$cimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName 'computername'

## Create the action
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument '-Command "c:\temp\systemrename.ps1"' -CimSession $cimSession

## Set to run as local system, No need to store Credentials!!!
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest -CimSession $cimSession

## set to run at startup could also do -AtLogOn for the trigger
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup -CimSession $cimSession

## register it (save it) and it will show up in default folder of task scheduler.
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -TaskName 'mytask' -TaskPath '\' -Principal $principal -Trigger $trigger -CimSession $cimSession

## clean up cimsession
Remove-CimSession -CimSession $cimSession
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the following setting in a GPO is not applying?:

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Disable the run once list
(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms815142.aspx)

When I had this setting applied by GPO and I tried to use the runonce reg key, the value I put in would still be in after a reboot, indicating Windows had not even attempted to run it.

Doing a Group Policy Result from Group Policy management (or whatever your favourite method of doing an RSoP [Resultant Set of Policy]) will show you all the GPOs applying to the computer/user, to allow you to narrow down which GPO is applying the setting.

Comment: This helped a lot but I checked these regkeys to find out if the RunOnce list was disabled `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `Set-ItemProperty` line to this:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RunOnceKey -Name 'NextRun' -Value 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -executionpolicy Bypass -File "~\Downloads\systemrename.ps1" '
```

It is probably the execution policy preventing the file from executing.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS, `runonce` triggers on user login, not startup. As per MS documentation:

> Run and RunOnce registry keys cause programs to run each time that a **user logs on**. The data value for a key is a command line no longer than 260 characters. Register programs to run by adding entries of the form description-string=commandline. You can write multiple entries under a key. If more than one program is registered under any particular key, the order in which those programs run is indeterminate.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys

The only way to do it is to create a scheduled task as described above or a service.

There used to be a `RunServicesOnce` registry key as referenced in the above document, but apparently that died along with Windows ME.